# Problems with jQuery code

Tags: jquery

Another jQuery issue...  I have tried this several times using "class" and "id" elements and I can not get it right. I am hoping the brains on stackoverflow can help!

The problem that I am having is when I open the page all of the elements are closed. When I click on one link all links open. I believe it closes correctly the problem is that when I open the first link all items open.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Bid Items</title>
<link href="bid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


  $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#showhideconent').hide(); 
  $('a').click(function(){ 
  $('#showhideconent').show('slow'); 

}); 

 $('a#close').click(function(){ 
        $('#showhideconent').hide('slow'); 
}) 

}); 

 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#showhideconent2').hide(); 
 $('a').click(function(){ 
 $('#showhideconent2').show('slow'); 

}); 

 $('a#close2').click(function(){ 
    $('#showhideconent2').hide('slow'); 
}) 

});  

  $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#showhideconent3').hide(); 
  $('a').click(function(){ 
 $('#showhideconent3').show('slow'); 

}); 

 $('a#close3').click(function(){ 
    $('#showhideconent3').hide('slow'); 
}) 

}); 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#showhideconent4').hide(); 
  $('a').click(function(){ 
  $('#showhideconent4').show('slow'); 

}); 

 $('a#close4').click(function(){ 
        $('#showhideconent4').hide('slow'); 
}) 

}); 


</script>

</head>

<body class="oneColElsCtr" onload="MM_preloadImages('Assignment4b.jpg')">

<div id="container">
<div id="mainContent">

    <h1>Bid Page</h1>
<h1>Coke Memorbila</h1>




<a href="#" id="click">Amber Bottle 1914</a>
<div id="box" align="center">
<div id="showhideconent">
<p><a href="coke/Amber1914.shtml"><img src="amber1914.jpg" width="200" height="200"    alt="Amber Coke" /></a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="close">Close</a> </p>

</div>
</div>


<a href="#" id="click">Amber Bottle 1915</a>
<div id="box" align="center">
<div id="showhideconent2">
<p><a href="coke/Amber1915.shtml"><img src="coke/Amber1914.shtml" width="200" height="200" alt="Amber Bottle 1915" /></a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="close2">Close</a> </p>


</div>
</div>




<a href="#" id="click">Green 1929</a>
<div id="box" align="center">
<div id="showhideconent3">
<p><a href="coke/green1929.shtml"><img src="green1929.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Green 1929" /></a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="close3">Close</a> </p>

</div>
</div>


<a href="#" id="click">1970s Cans</a>
<div id="box" align="center">
<div id="showhideconent4">
<p><a href="coke/tincans.shtml"><img src="coke_tincan.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Tin Cans" /></a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="close4">Close</a> </p>


</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please describe the problem more clearly. Also, why do you have so many `.ready` calls? Can't you just put it all in a single invokation?

Comment: 1) Code isn't copy'n'paste'n'runnable without changes. Link to code.jquery.com instead and get rid of that Frontpage MM_xxx onload function. 2) The functional requirement isn't clear. Clarify more.

Comment: I'm pretty sure MM_ is from dreamweaver MM=MacroMedia

Comment: @ Marcelo - Yes, I've tried using class elements instead of ID tags but I still could not get it to work.. I got frustrated and made them all ID elements.  Thanks

Comment: do you see anything wrong with 'poblems'?  makes me think its highly likely you have a typo... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Michael, see my answer from earlier when you asked about it.

I re-wrote your HTML and jQuery code to work.

[Problems with show hide jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752140/problems-with-show-hide-jquery)

<s>It is good that you're not reusing IDs anymore, but</s> you don't need IDs to assign event handlers when you have consistent repetition like you have.

---

**EDIT:**

No offense, but it sounds like you just need to pick up a book on jQuery and read a few chapters. You'll be surprised how easy jQuery is to comprehend when you have a little guidance.

I didn't know any jQuery, but after reading a little bit of **Learning jQuery** I had a good grip on the basic concepts. It only took a couple hours of my time.

---

**EDIT:**

You can see the repetition here.

```
<a href="#" class="click">Green 1929</a>
<div class="box" align="center">
    <div class="showhideconent">
        <p><a href="coke/green1929.shtml"><img src="green1929.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Green 1929" /></a></p>
        <p><a href="#" class="close">Close</a> </p>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="click">1970s Cans</a>
<div class="box" align="center">
    <div class="showhideconent">
        <p><a href="coke/tincans.shtml"><img src="coke_tincan.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Tin Cans" /></a></p>
        <p><a href="#" class="close">Close</a> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

First, I changed the `a` elements so that they have `class="click"` instead of `id="click"`.

They are obviously intended to play a similar role, but on different content. Let's say that there are 20 such sections with a `click` class. I can assign an event handler to all twenty at once with:

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    // Do something.
});
```

But, of course, we want each one to only act on the content it is associated with. Also, we need to make sure we are working with the correct one that was clicked. To accomplish this, we use the `this` keyword. It refers to the element that received the event.

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $(this) // Places the element that was clicked in a jQuery object.
    // Do something.
});
```

So now what do we do? Well, it looks like you wanted to use that to show the content. So we need to locate that link's associated content, and show it.

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $(this).next().find('.showhidecontent').show();
    return false;  // This return statement can be used to disable the default behavior of the link. Sometimes necessary
});
```

This code almost explains itself. `$(this)` (the element we clicked) grabs the `next()` element (the one with class `.box`) then searches for an element with class `.showhidecontent` inside of it, then shows it.

You could do something similar with your `.close` button. It is even easier since it is inside the `.showhidecontent` element.

```
$('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.showhidecontent').hide();
    return false;  // This return statement can be used to disable the default behavior of the link. Sometimes necessary
});
```

This assigns the function to all elements with `.close` class. When clicked, the one that was clicked searches for the `closest()` parent with class `.showhidecontent`, and then hides it.

---

**EDIT:**

To put it all together, this code will assign the proper events to all the repeating sections, as long as you fix the classes. (You can pretty much ditch the IDs)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showhidecontent').hide();  // Hide all the showhidecontent class elements

        // Assign click event handler to all .click class elements
    $('.click').click(function() {
        $(this).next().find('.showhidecontent').show();
        return false;  // This return statement can be used to disable the default behavior of the link. Sometimes necessary
    });

        // Assign click event handler to all .close class elements
    $('.close').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.showhidecontent').hide();
        return false;  // This return statement can be used to disable the default behavior of the link. Sometimes necessary
    });
});
```

Hope this helps. jQuery is designed to be very readable, but you need to learn the basics first (just like in anything you do).

Comment: This is my first attempt!  Yes, I know I have a long ways to go.  But I realy apprecate the help!

Comment: First ever attempt was today.

Comment: You'll be doing yourself a huge favor if you just read the first few chapters of a jQuery book, or an online tutorial. The best answers here won't do you much good if you haven't learned the basic concepts. One great thing about jQuery is that the code is really easy to read and understand, but you do need a foundation first. It won't take you long, and will pay off greatly.

Comment: One very important thing is what many others have mentioned. Two elements must not have the same ID. In your code above, there are several elements that have the id `box`. It will just cause problems for you. An ID is a unique identifier. A class is what you give elements that are similar in nature. I'll edit my answer here to show what I mean.

Comment: Thank for to info...  That was way more than I ever expected what you provided has been extremely helpful

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$("a")` returns *all* <a> elements on the page. So you effectively bind your "show" function to *every* link. When the event fires, jQuery simply fires each handler in turn and all your contents get shown.

What you've got is actually pretty inefficient (in terms of code duplication) you can do it with much less code like this. Assuming this is your HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="click">Amber Bottle 1914</a> 
<div class="showhideconent"> 
  <p><a href="coke/Amber1914.shtml"><img src="amber1914.jpg" width="200" height="200"    alt="Amber Coke" /></a></p> 
  <p><a href="#" id="close">Close</a> </p> 
</div> 

<a href="#" class="click">Amber Bottle 1915</a> 
<div class="showhideconent"> 
  <p><a href="coke/Amber1915.shtml"><img src="coke/Amber1914.shtml" width="200" height="200" alt="Amber Bottle 1915" /></a></p> 
  <p><a href="#" id="close2">Close</a> </p> 
</div> 

<a href="#" class="click">Green 1929</a> 
<div class="showhideconent"> 
  <p><a href="coke/green1929.shtml"><img src="green1929.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Green 1929" /></a></p> 
  <p><a href="#" id="close3">Close</a> </p> 
</div> 

<a href="#" class="click">1970s Cans</a> 
<div class="showhideconent"> 
  <p><a href="coke/tincans.shtml"><img src="coke_tincan.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Tin Cans" /></a></p> 
  <p><a href="#" id="close4">Close</a> </p>
</div>
```

Note that you cannot have multiple elements with the same ID, so I've changed a couple of your IDs to classes. I've simplified it a little, so you might have to add some thing back if it's required for styling. Now you can use the following javascript:

```
$(function() {

  $("a.click").click(function() {
    // this will be called whenever a <a class="click"> link is clicked
    // 'this' will refer to the actual <a> tag itself so we can use that to
    // find the next <div class="showhidecontent"> to show/hide
    $(this).next(".showhidecontent").toggle("slow");
  });

});
```

This code will register a "click" handler with each <a class="click"> tag that, when clicked will toggle the *next* "showhidecontent" element in the document.

Answer (score 0):

First, IDs are unique, you can't have two identical IDs (Well, you can but you shouldn't). Second, you don't need several `$(document).ready(function(){ });`, one is enough. And finally, solving your issue, this `$('a').click(function(){ });` will bind the `click()` event to every single `a` tag you have.

Try something like:

```
<a href="#" id="click-3">Green 1929</a>
<div id="box" align="center">
    <div id="showhideconent3">
        <p><a href="coke/green1929.shtml"><img src="green1929.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Green 1929" /></a></p>
        <p><a href="#" id="close3">Close</a> </p>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="click-4">1970s Cans</a>
<div id="box" align="center">
    <div id="showhideconent4">
        <p><a href="coke/tincans.shtml"><img src="coke_tincan.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Tin Cans" /></a></p>
        <p><a href="#" id="close4">Close</a> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#showhideconent-3, #showhideconent-4').hide();
    $('#click-3').click(function(){ 
        $('#showhideconent-3').show('slow');
    }
    $('#click-4').click(function(){ 
        $('#showhideconent-4').show('slow');
    }
});
```